# Odd jquery animation behavior

Tags: jquery

I have two events going on
 1st You click an image it moves and expands
 2nd you click outside the image and it moves and shrinks back to it's org. position.

for some reason when you click the outside area you have to wait for like 30 seconds for the animation to fire (the shrinking)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var titles=new Array("1","2","3", "4","5", "6", "7", "8","9");

     var image=0;
     var p;     

$('.grid li').click(function() { 
 var location =$(this).index();
 image = $(this).position();  

 $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: 1, top:'15px'},800,function() {
    $(this).siblings().css("top", "0px");
    p =$(this).parent().detach();
    $('.pop_image img ').css( "left", image.left);
    $('.pop_image img').css("top", image.top);
    $('.pop_title ').css( "left", image.left);
    $('.pop_title').css("top", image.top-50);                  

    $('.pop_image img').animate({marginLeft: '20%',marginRight: '20%', marginTop: '20%', top: '0', left: '0'},800);          
    $('.pop_image img').attr("src", location+1 +".jpg");
    $('.pop_title').animate({marginLeft: '20%',marginRight: '20%', marginTop: '20%', top: '-50px', left: '0'},800);
    $('.pop_title ').text(titles[location]);
    $('.pop_title').animate({fontSize: '200%'},800);      
    $('.pop_image img').animate({width:'679px', height:'422px'},800);      
      });
 });   

$('#hidden').click(function() {     

  $('.pop_title').animate({fontSize: '100%'},800);      
  $('.pop_image img').animate({width:'339px', height:'211px'},800);    
  $('.pop_image img').animate({left: image.left, right: image.top },800);   
  $('.pop_title').animate({left: image.left, right: image.top },800);   
     });  
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/51/)

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle or similar for us to test?

Comment: It takes so long before they animate because some elements are still animating. I don't know which that are but you need to solve that. Or you can add `$('*').clearQueue()` to your `$('#hidden').click` event handler to stop all elements on your page.

Comment: putVande. that makes sense thanks for the help! The .clearQueue() worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's taking very long because of this:

```
$(this).siblings().animate({opacity: 1, top:'15px'},800,function() {
```

That will loop through every sibling and animate them at 800 ms... so, 9 images that's a total of 27 seconds before the rest of your code executes.

I simplified your animation quite a bit... so it's working now, but obviously will still need a little adjusting.

http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/80/

var titles=new Array("1","2","3", "4","5", "6", "7", "8","9");

```
 var image=0;
 var p;
```

$('.grid li').click(function() { 
 var location =$(this).index();
 image = $(this).position();

```
$(this).siblings().animate({"opacity":1,"top": "0px"});
p = $(this).parent().detach();
 $('.pop_image img ').css({
     "left":image.left,
     "top":image.top
 });
 $('.pop_title ').css({
     "left":image.left,
     "top":image.top-50
 });              

$('.pop_image img').animate({marginLeft: '20%',marginRight: '20%', marginTop: '20%', top: '0', left: '0',width:'679px', height:'422px'},800);          
$('.pop_title').animate({marginLeft: '20%',marginRight: '20%', marginTop: '20%', top: '-50px', left: '0',fontSize: '200%'},800);
$('.pop_title ').text(titles[location]);  

  });


$('#hidden').click(function() {
  $('.pop_title').animate({fontSize: '100%',left: image.left, right: image.top},800);      
  $('.pop_image img').animate({width:'339px', height:'211px',left: image.left, right: image.top},800);     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Tim, your animations just take a long time what stops any other code from executing.

What you could do is add `stop()` functions to your animations or you could add :

```
$('*').clearQueue() to your '$('#hidden').click(...` function.
```

Which stops all current animations on your page to stop.
You can change the `$('*')` to `$('.grid')` to stop all animations within your `<ul class="grid">`

See http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ for more info about the `clearQueue` function.